# How to check who has done what in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, logging

In my production DB, everyday I find some values have been changed. Is there any way to check who has done these changes? These changes must have been done by logging into the DB itself. I need to who has done it and when.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the values changed in tables?  Or are they properties of the database?  If they are in tables then you can implement trigger-based auditing on your tables as described in [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/27/adding-simple-trigger-based-auditing-to-your-sql-server-database.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to set up auditing on your tables.